# php regex check first char optimization

Tags: php, regex

I heard that regex are slow.
So I wondered which code would be more efficient, given that the pattern I'm looking for starts with an arobase:

This one ?

```
if(preg_match('!^@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$!', $subject, $match)){
    // do something
}
```

Or this one ?

```
if(
    '@' === substr($subject, 0, 1) && 
    preg_match('!^@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$!', $subject, $match)
){
    // do something
}
```

I guess I will run some custom tests...

Comment: Use a profiler on your whole application. Just preoptimizing a single code section on heirloom advise is often a waste of time. You'll find that loops and SQL queries are what's worth bothering with.

Comment: For most purposes, the speed of regexp is not an issue unless you write a bad one ("catastrophic backtracking"). I wouldn't worry about speed in your case. If you need to, benchmark it. Premature optimisation is a much bigger problem than regexp speed.

Comment: are you using regx for email validation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad optimization. Better if u will use profiler and optimise only code that need to be optimised.

But this code can be optimised by string array access trick.

```
if('@' === $subject[0] && preg_match('!^@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$!', $subject, $match)){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even if it may not be a great optimization, 
it might be good to know which solution works faster.

I made a list of 10000 entries looking all like this: 0RKYui3rkn  (10 random char, none of them is an arobase).
The results are roughly (refreshing the browser multiple times and computing an average value mentally and approximately):
- only regex: 0.031390190124512,
- if substr and regex: 0.022544145584106
- if 0 === strpos and regex: 02040696144104
- $subject[0] and regex: 0072059631347656

So the winner is clearly the string array access trick.
Hope this could help someone else.